# Creating Strongly Connected Components from a DAG

Tags: algorithm, graph, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am trying to create strongly connected components from a directed acyclic graph.

The input is a list of edges in form

```
1 2
3 5
etc
```

I need to create an outpoint of a minimal set of edges to be added to the given graph to make a graph of strongly connected components....

Any ideas?

Here's an example of what I'm looking for:

Given the input:

```
1 3
1 4
2 3
2 4
5 7
5 8
6 8
6 9
```

The output would be the minimum number of edges necessary for addition to create strongly connected components.

Output:

```
3 1
4 5
7 6
8 1
9 2
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. Each vertex by itself forms a strongly connected component. So you don't have to add any edges.. But I guess you have a different question in mind ?

Comment: @krjampani What you say is true... however when there is a graph and they may not be connected, these become components. I am trying to create an algorithm that will connect these unconnected graphs efficiently so that they become strongly connected components.

Comment: So you want to convert each weakly connected component into a strongly connected component ? IF the weakly connected component is a DAG, you can make it strongly connected by adding all possible edges from the sink vertices to the source vertices. These would also be minimal.

Comment: @krjampani This makes a lot of sense! I'm trying to get the complexity of this down to linear time. Is this possible? ideas?

Comment: Can you add new vertices to the graph to make it strongly connected ? Do you want exactly one strongly connected component at the end ? Can you provide an example of what you want ?

Comment: @krjampani I will update my post with an example. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming there are no isolated vertices in the graph you only need to add max(|sources|,|sinks|) edges to make it strongly connected.

Let T={t<sub>1</sub>,…,t<sub>n</sub>} be the sinks and {s<sub>1</sub>,…,s<sub>m</sub>} be the sources of the DAG. Assume that n <= m. (The other case is very similar). Consider a bipartite graph G(T,S) between the two sets defined as follows. G(T,S) has an edge (t<sub>i</sub>,s<sub>j</sub>) if and only if t<sub>i</sub> can be reached from s<sub>j</sub>.

Let M be a maximal matching in G(T,S). Without loss of generality assume that M consists of k edges: {(t<sub>1</sub>,s<sub>1</sub>),(t<sub>2</sub>,s<sub>2</sub>),…,(t<sub>k</sub>,s<sub>k</sub>)}. In the original graph DAG G, add directed-edges {(t<sub>1</sub>->s<sub>2</sub>),(t<sub>2</sub>->s<sub>3</sub>),…,(t<sub>k−1</sub>->s<sub>k</sub>),(t<sub>k</sub>->s<sub>1</sub>)}. It's easy to see that by adding these edges, the vertices induced by M are strongly connected in G.

Now consider the remaining vertices in G(T,S). Because M maximal, each vertex in S−M (resp. T−M)should be connected to a vertex in T (resp. S−M). So we pair up the remaining vertices arbitrarily, say {(t<sub>k+1</sub>,s<sub>k+1</sub>),…,(t<sub>n</sub>,s<sub>n</sub>)} and add the corresponding directed edges in G. For each remaining source vertex source s<sub>i</sub> (i belongs to {n+1,…,m} we add the edge (t<sub>1</sub>->s<sub>i</sub>) in G. Thus the total number of edges added is max(|sources|,|sinks|).

**EDIT: Adding a couple of Examples**

For the example in your input. We fist compute a maximal matching, say:

```
3--1
4--2
7--5
8--6
```

So we add the edges:

```
3->2
4->5
7->6
8->1
```

The remaining (sink) vertex not present in the matching is 9 and so we add the arc from 9 to any source vertex in the matching, say `9->1`.

Here's another example that illustrates all the steps of the algorithm:

Input Graph:

```
12 3   5    9 10  (sources)
\|/   /|\    \/
 4   6 7 8   11   (sinks)
```

Maximal Matching:

```
4--1
6--5
11--9
```

So we add the edges:

```
4->5
6->9
11->1
```

Now the remaining sinks are `{7, 8}` and the remaining sources are `{2, 3, 10}`. We arbitrary pair 7 with say 2 and 8 with say 3 and add:

```
7->2
8->3
```

Finally, the remaining (source) vertex is 10 and we add:

```
4->10
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I am having trouble digesting it though... do you think you might go step by step through it with my example data? I'm doing this currently but I'm not quite there. I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: You are welcome. Added a couple of examples. Hope they make it more clear.

Comment: Upvote a million times! However, I do have a couple more clarifying issues... First, can you explain more about the maximal matching? and how you identify it? And secondly, I count 7 edges being added to your example. Shouldn't there only be 5 according to the assumption that the minimum number of added vertices should be MAX(source,sink) because source = 5 and sink = 5?

Comment: *number of added edges (not vertices)

Comment: You are right. There is a small problem with the second example. Fixed it now. But note that the number of source is 6 and so there are 6 edges that need to be added.

Comment: A matching in a graph is a set of disjoint edges (disjoint means that no two edges can share a vertex). A maximal matching is simply a matching that cannot be extended. You can obtain it by greedily choosing edges such that they are disjoint from the previously chosen edges. See the Wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17530/discussion-between-krjampani-and-zax)

Comment: I'm new to chat, so I posted in there, but not sure if it expires or not. Let me know if it does. If not I look forward to your response

Comment: I'm new as well. I didn't realize that the chat was already created. I have now added my comments in the chat.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, You should use an Adjacency Matrix representation of your graph. Initially, it will be a sparse matrix with 1s or something where your current edges are.

Using a simple traversal of the matrix, all 0 elements -> 1 that you require to create SCCs, and each of those transformations will be an edge you need to add.

There is also a good wiki page showing the possible popular algorithms used for this:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component

It recommends [Tarjan's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm) and [Path-based](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path-based_strong_component_algorithm) algorithms as being the most practical.

Comment: I just read the algorithms and have two follow up questions. 1. From my reading it seems that those algorithms are utilized to identify the strongly connected components, not to find which edges need to be added in order to create them, so I'm unsure how to implement it. and 2. If I use the adjacency matrix representation and simply make all 0 elements to 1 to create a new edge, I would end up with a completely connected graph wouldn't I? not the minimum number of edges to add to create strongly connected components